# How to use jest-sonar-reporter?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, sonarqube

How to use jest-sonar-reporter? In `config.json` we were using `"testResultsProcessor": "/config/jest/resultsProcessor"`:

resultsProcessor.js

```
module.exports = (results) => {
process.env.TEST_REPORT_PATH = root('reports/unit')
process.env.JEST_SUITE_NAME = 'React Unit Tests'
process.env.JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT = root('reports/unit/junit.xml')
require(root('node_modules/jest-sonar-reporter/index')).apply(this, [results])
require(root('node_modules/jest-junit/index')).apply(this, [results])
// add any other processor you need
return results
}
```

this was working fine when we were using `"jest": "^21.2.1"`,
but after updating Jest to `"jest": "^26.1.0"`,

as per documentation...

```
"reporters": [ "default",[
"jest-junit", {
"outputDirectory":"reports/unit",
"suiteName": "ANZ-React-BoilerPlate Unit Tests",
"outputName": "junit.xml"
}]],
```

`jest-junit` is working fine but how to support `jest-sonar-reporter`?

Comment: *"after updating Jest"* what, exactly - it seems like you forgot to include the actual *problem*. [That library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-sonar-reporter) was last published two years ago and [its repo](https://github.com/3dmind/jest-sonar-reporter) is archived, so it's possible it simply won't work with newer version of Jest.

Comment: The main help I needed is, I just wanted to use jest-sonar-reporter.

Comment: I solved this issue with latest jest using jest-sonar npm package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this using jest-sonar npm package.